# Apps Script Copy and Paste Rows if Condition is Met

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Now, I’m using Apps Script in Google Sheet. I’ve a few pages with respective details for each quotation number. How to Copy and Paste specific rows from specific sheets to its same sheet at the bottom(after last row) when condition is met. Let say, I need all details for GE-2108-0271-Rev.0 quotation number in few pages to be copy and paste at the same sheet itself. And the quotation number increment by 1 . So it would be GE-2108-0271-Rev.1 after paste it. To be exact, here is an example: Page 1: to be exact I need the number increment by 1 from GE-2108-0271-Rev.0 to GE-2108-0271-Rev.1 (column 2)

Now, I've tried to use this coding with other data in other file its work. But when i'm using my own data. The range is undefined.

```
//*GLOBALS*
var SpreadsheetID = "1Zgs1jzjIeaBpd5Ms7emQgxhVJBMtlEOlDNDfxlhSRiY";


function myFunctionn() {
  var SheetName1 = "M-Front";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SpreadsheetID)
  var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName(SheetName1);
 
  // Get the last row based on the data range of a single column.
  var lastRow = sheet1.getLastRow();
   
  //EXAMPLE: Get the data range based on our selected columns range.
  var dataRange = sheet1.getRange(lastRow,1, 1, sheet1.getLastColumn());
  var dataValues = dataRange.getValues();
  
  //Get value from column A & Column Cof last row
  var FoundName=dataValues[0][0];    //Get Quotation
  var RevNo=dataValues[0][12];        //Get Rev (Column M:M)

//********CHECK ROWS WITH SAME NAME IN DETALS SHEET********/

  var SheetName2 = "M-Items";
  var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName(SheetName2);    
 
  // Get the last row based on the data range of a single column.
  var lastRow2 = sheet2.getLastRow();
  var lastColumn2 = sheet2.getLastColumn();

  //EXAMPLE: Get the data range based on our selected columns range.
  var dataRange2 = sheet2.getRange(1,1, lastRow2, lastColumn2);
  var dataValues2 = dataRange2.getValues();
  var dataMatch=[];
  //***** */
  // Loop through array and if condition met, add relevant
  // background color.
  var p=0 ; //Column No. for Name column A:A
  var q=2; //Column No. for RevNo COlumn C:C
  
  for ( j = 0 ; j < lastRow2 ; j++){
    if(dataValues2[j][p] === FoundName && dataValues2[j][q] === RevNo-1 ){
       var range = sheet2.getRange(j+1, 1, 1, lastColumn2); 
      sheet2.insertRowsAfter(sheet2.getLastRow(), 1);
      range.copyTo(sheet2.getRange(sheet2.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, lastColumn2), {contentsOnly:false});
      
      //To update Rev No.
      //var Temp0=range.getValues();
      // var Temp1=Temp0[0][3];   //Read Revision No
      var m=sheet2.getLastRow();
      var n='C' + String(m);
      var Temp=sheet2.getRange(n);
      Temp.setValue(RevNo);
      
      //To update Quotation No
      var Temp2=range.getValues();
      var Temp3=Temp2[0][0];   //Read Name
      //var Temp4=Temp2[0][3];   //Read Revision No
      var Temp5 = String(Temp3) + String(RevNo);
      var z='B' + String(m);
      var Temp3=sheet2.getRange(z);
      Temp3.setValue(Temp5);      
    };
  };
};
```

Comment: What exact error are you receiving? At which line? @Biha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ehi, I would work with getValues and setValues and then with array of arrays to obtain the result to copy around. i recommend you to read [the App-script-Best-Practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices)

eg `[[Car,4],[Motorbike,2],[plane,3]]`

```
// Take the initial data that you need to copy around, i would take the entire sheet directly with getDataRange()
var dataToCopy = yourSheet.getDataRange().getValues();

// Create the result that will be copied if condition is met combining a cycle with an if function
var arrayResult = []; // Here i create an array
for(y in dataToCopy){
if(dataToCopy[y][column] == yourCondition){
arrayResult.push(dataToCopy[y]) //here i start to populate the arrayResult with the row of dataToCopy that respect the condition above
 }
}

// Copy the result where you need them
sheetFinal.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(),1,arrayResult.length,arrayResult[0].length).setValues(arrayResult)

//arrayResult.length is the number of rows or how many times the condition was met or the length of the array of arrays
//arrayResult[0].length is the number of columns or the length of the first row or the length of the first array
```